# Task Canceled exception on RavenDB when creating indexes

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, ravendb

I'm having an issue trying to create indexes on RavenDB 3.5

When creating more than 3 indexes the application just dies, getting a

> Unable to connect to the remote server Status Code: ConnectFailure

The index creation code is farely straight forward:

```
    private static void CreateIndexes(IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        new PurchaseOrder_QueryByExternalReference().Execute(documentStore);
        new SupplierDocument_QueryBySupplierName().Execute(documentStore);
        new ProductDocument_QueryByProductIdAndName().Execute(documentStore);
        new PurchaseOrderLine_QueryableIndex().Execute(documentStore);
        new PurchaseOrderLine_ForPurchaseOrderIndex().Execute(documentStore);
    }
```

But the same happens if the

> IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(MyIndexClass).Assembly, store);

method is called. This happens with any 3 indexes from the list on any order.

Full stack-trace is this:

> exception
>   {"A task was canceled."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       Etag: null
>       HResult: -2146233088
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: null
>       Message: "A task was canceled."
>       Response: {StatusCode: 503, ReasonPhrase: 'Service Unavailable', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:
>   {
>   }}
>       ResponseString: "Unable to connect to the remote server Status Code: ConnectFailure"
>       Source: "Raven.Client.Lightweight"
>       StackTrace: "   at Raven.Client.Connection.Implementation.HttpJsonRequest.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Implementation\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 258
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.Implementation.HttpJsonRequest.d__38`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\\Raven.Client.Lightweight\\Connection\\Implementation\\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 312
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.Implementation.HttpJsonRequest.<ReadResponseJsonAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\\Raven.Client.Lightweight\\Connection\\Implementation\\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 221
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<GetIndexAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\\Raven.Client.Lightweight\\Connection\\Async\\AsyncServerClient.cs:line 726
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformerBase`1.d__34`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\\Raven.Client.Lightweight\\Connection\\ReplicationInformerBase.cs:line 417
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformerBase`1.d__33`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\\Raven.Client.Lightweight\\Connection\\ReplicationInformerBase.cs:line 316
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.<ExecuteWithReplication>d__164`1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Async\AsyncServerClient.cs:line 0
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Raven.Abstractions.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\\Raven.Abstractions\\Util\\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 75
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>       at Raven.Abstractions.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Abstractions\Util\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 89
>       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.GetIndex(String name) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 222\
>      at Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask.Execute(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention documentConvention) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Indexes\AbstractIndexCreationTask.cs:line 304
>      at Raven.Client.DocumentStoreBase.ExecuteIndex(AbstractIndexCreationTask indexCreationTask) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\DocumentStoreBase.cs:line 102
>      at Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask.Execute(IDocumentStore store) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Indexes\AbstractIndexCreationTask.cs:line 221
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.RavenDb.RavenDbDocumentStoreFactory.CreateIndexes(IDocumentStore documentStore) in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\RavenDb\RavenDbDocumentStoreFactory.cs:line 50
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.RavenDb.RavenDbDocumentStoreFactory.ConfigureDocumentStore(IDocumentStore documentStore) in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\RavenDb\RavenDbDocumentStoreFactory.cs:line 38
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.RavenDb.RavenDbDocumentStoreFactory.Create(String ravenDbLocation, String ravenDbDatabase) in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\RavenDb\RavenDbDocumentStoreFactory.cs:line 22
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.PersistenceAdapter.<.ctor>b__8_0() in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\PersistenceAdapter.cs:line 53
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.PersistenceAdapter.RegisterRavenDbUtilities() in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\PersistenceAdapter.cs:line 175
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.PersistenceAdapter.RegisterRavenLogic() in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\PersistenceAdapter.cs:line 86
>      at Persistence.Database.Adapter.PersistenceAdapter.Initialize() in \my\route\Persistence.Database.Adapter\PersistenceAdapter.cs:line 74
>      at My-Program.ConfigurePersistentAdapter(Settings settings) in \my\route\MessageQueueListener\MessageQueueListenerService.cs:line 153
>      at My-Program.AddBootstrapperExtension() in \my\route\net-stock-purchasing-service.MessageQueueListener\MessageQueueListenerService.cs:line 118
>      at My-Program.Startup() in \my\route\net-stock-purchasing-service.MessageQueueListener\MessageQueueListenerService.cs:line 78"
>       StatusCode: ServiceUnavailable
>       TargetSite: {Void MoveNext()}

Comment: This typically means that there is some sort of a timeout. Depending on your index, it may take a LOT of time to prepare it. What does fiddler say?

Comment: @AyendeRahienwhy could there be a timeout? all indexes are very small in code, or do you mean on the amount of data that will be indexed due to it?

Comment: I'm not sure. The Fiddler trace should have more information

Comment: Any update on this? i'm facing same issue with an empty db & 5 indexes exactly in the line where i call `store.ExecuteIndexes(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be due to a mismatch of ravendb client library and the installed server. My application was running the latest version of the RavenDB client and the server is using version 3.0

Answer (score 4):

When RavenDB 3.5 was release, something broke in the client package.

If you are running [RavenDB.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/) from 3.0.30000 to 3.0.30179, then it should work.

If you are running a higher version, then you will encounter (in certain conditions) this exception. To resolve that, you can use an [alternate API](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/client-api/commands/indexes/put): `store.DatabaseCommands.PutIndexes`.

```
var indexes = new List<AbstractIndexCreationTask>();
indexes.Add(new MyIndex1());
indexes.Add(new MyIndex2());
indexes.Add(new MyIndex....());

var transfos = new List<AbstractTransformerCreationTask>();
transfos.Add(new MyTransformer1());
transfos.Add(new MyTransformer2());
transfos.Add(new MyTransformer...());

// put indexes in 1 command
var indexesToPut = IndexCreation.CreateIndexesToAdd(indexes, documentStore.Conventions);
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutIndexes(indexesToPut);

// don't forget transformers
foreach (var item in transfos)
{
    item.Execute(Store);
}
```

This should solve your problem.

I was encountering this problem after upgrading my client package. Note that the exception occurred only in console applications and not in my web applications.

Answer (score 1):

That solved the issue for me:

```
var indexes = IndexCreation.CreateIndexesToAdd(new List<AbstractIndexCreationTask> {...}, store.Conventions);

var alreadyExisting = store.DatabaseCommands.GetIndexes(0, 128)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Name);

foreach (var index in indexes.Where(i => !alreadyExisting.ContainsKey(i.Name)))
    store.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex(index.Name, index.Definition);

store.DatabaseCommands.PutIndexes(indexes);
```

Comment: Can you explain this code? It seems you `PutIndex` the non-existing indexes and then you push them again in the `PutIndexes`. Is there documentation about the old-fashioned way being broken?